# Autocomplete text input in Sheets

Tags: validation, google-sheets, autocomplete

Starting with an empty column, as it is progressively populated with text I want to autocomplete any repeated text. I tried Data Validation, defined the range as 1-1000, set checkbox to NOT, Reject Input etc but receive a message that the range of cells must not intersect. 
How can I escape from this as the range for collecting the data (after the first entry) is the same as the range where I want to enter the data which may be duplicated above.
I seem to be chasing my own tail!

Comment: First, it would be great if we could get some additional info about your problem. Maybe add a short example that shows your problem. Second, have you tried to write the output to a different column and then copying it to the correct one?

Comment: The database has a list: Grey joggers, Orange top, Grey hoodie, Khaki leggings, etc. This is part of a large database with multiple attributes accessed via drop-down menus. The particular field is a free-text column to capture a personal description of the garment. As you will see, the word 'Grey' occurs twice: so, what I want is that, the moment Sheets next sees 'Grey' it provides the option of Grey joggers, Grey hoodies, etc with a progressively long list as the data entries accumulate. When I try to use Data Validation for the column I get a message 'The selected ranges cannot intersect'.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. When filling in a column top to bottom you want the current entry to be autocompleted with what you typed in earlier. When I typed in your examples in a fresh Sheet it worked out of the box. [Here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/9063842?hl=en&msgid=15249172) they say that there should not be an empty row between the entries you want to use autocomplete on.